# Spoofing HTTP Referrer data using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, referrer, spoofing

Answers on here and various other sites are often full of warnings not to trust HTTP Referrer headers because they are 'so easily' spoofed or faked.

Before I go any further - no, I'm not up to no good - but I do want to run some referrer-dependant tests.

Whilst I don't doubt that the warnings about fake referrers are true, I can't really find much detailed info on *how* they can be manipulated. Even the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spoofing) only talks about it in general terms.

I'm about to play with the [RefControl addin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) for FireFox.

Programatically (in ASP.NET specifically) the [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is a read-only property, so I don't see how I can fire off requests with fake referrer data if I can't set it? Do I really have to do it manually?

How would I use ASP.NET to send a request to my site with a user-supplied variable to populate the referrer header?

**EDIT :** As per my comment below, I ideally want to take an incoming request, manupulate the referrer data and then pass the request on to another page, intact. If I can make it *appear* intact by building a new one from scratch and copying the original properties, then that is fine too.

Comment: You mean [WebRequest.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx) to send the request, not ASP.NET? Or are you unit-testing your pages without actually going through a web request, i.e. you need to mock the context classes so you can modify them?

Comment: Well, I thought I'd use ASP.NET to perform a sort of "passthrough" request, i.e. when I visit my test page, it simply manipulates the referrer before passing my request on to another page. If I can do that with WebRequest, then the answer to your question is "yes"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this exactly what you want, but in general, you should be able to spoof the value of the `UrlReferer` property (even if it's read-only) in `HttpContext.Current.Request` by using a bit of reflection.

For example:

```
FieldInfo fi = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetType().GetField("_referrer", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

string initialReferer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
if (fi != null)
    fi.SetValue(HttpContext.Current.Request, new Uri("http://example.com"));
string fakedReferer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

On VS; these are the values before and after changing the UrlReferrer:

```
initialReferer
"http://localhost/Test/Default.aspx"
fakedReferer
"http://example.com/"
```

If you open the System.Web assembly using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) you'll notice that the UrlReferrer property looks something like this:

```
public Uri UrlReferrer
{
    get
    {
        if (this._referrer == null && this._wr != null)
        {
            string knownRequestHeader = this._wr.GetKnownRequestHeader(36);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(knownRequestHeader))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (knownRequestHeader.IndexOf("://", StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
                    {
                        this._referrer = new Uri(knownRequestHeader);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this._referrer = new Uri(this.Url, knownRequestHeader);
                    }
                }
                catch (HttpException)
                {
                    this._referrer = null;
                }
            }
        }
        return this._referrer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. If I use `Response.Redirect`, the fake referrer isn't preserved, but it does work with `Server.Transfer`.

Comment: @Widor interesting, but makes sense. Response.Redirect does a round roundtrip to the browser and back to the server.

Answer (score 3):

This likely isn't going to get you what you want. But you can edit the Referror of an HttpWebRequest. I don't think there is a way of editing the referrer of your request in context.

```
using System.Net;

HttpWebRequest Req= (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://somewhere.com/");
Req.Referer = "http://www.fakesite.com";
```